# Условный джойн по наличию записей

Tags: sql, инспекция-кода, firebird

Есть две таблицы `A` (`id1`, `id2`) и `B` (`id`, `a_id1`, `a_id2`, ...). В `A` порядка 10-20 записей. В `B` десятки тысяч. Индексы `A(id1, id2)` и `B(a_id1, a_id2)` в наличии.

Нужно в одном запросе объединить два таких запроса

```sql
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a)) THEN
  SELECT
    b.*
  FROM
    b
    JOIN a ON (
      a.id1 = b.a_id1 AND
      a.id2 = b.a_id2
    );
ELSE
  SELECT
    b.*
  FROM
    b;
```

Можно что-то придумать?

Все происходит в процедуре, поэтому можно предварительно выполнить какие-то действия.

Писать два запроса не хочу, т.к. у запроса может быть еще куча параметров по таблице `B`

---

**Update**

Наваял так. На сколько дико?

```sql
SELECT
  b.*
FROM
  b
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a) OR
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM a 
    WHERE
      a.id1 = b.a_id1 AND a.id2 = b.a_id2
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

> На сколько дико?

Второй вариант вполне нормальный, если в таблице `a` не бывает большого количества записей или добавлены индексы, удобные для выборки.

**Upadte**

Дополню, раз уж местное сообщество недовольно столь коротким ответом.

Изначально interbase (наследником которого является firebird) не был рассчитан на сложные запросы. Всю логику предполагалось реализовывать в хранимых процедурах на IF'ах и циклах. С этой точки зрения для производительности лучше оставить ветвление с двумя разными запросами.

Если `SELECT b.* FROM b` идет в цикле с неявным курсом `FOR ... DO ...`, то есть еще один вариант:

1. Перед циклом делаете проверку `IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a))` и результат сохраняете в переменную-флаг.
2. В цикле проверяете флаг, и если он не установлен, то выполняете проверку `IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.id1 = :a_id1 AND a.id2 = :a_id2))` в зависимости от результата которой или продолжаете обработку или переходите к следующей итерации (`CONTINUE` );

Comment: В `A` порядка 10-20 записей. В `B` десятки тысяч. Индексы `A(id1, id2)` и `B(a_id1, a_id2)` в наличии